# Django static files : use only /static/ directory

Tags: python, django, nginx, static

I have a Django live version in production and I develop in local with Django manager.py.
I'm not able to find the correct configuration settings for my static files.

All my static files are on a /static/ on the root of the project, because all the sub-apps use the same stylesheets and so on.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

On my live version : it works because I've got an NGINX rule that allow access to /static/ directly.

But when I want to work on local, the static files are 404, with Debug True and False.

I don't see the interest for my needings of the staticfiles directory (but I can have a wrong mind here).

Is it possible to have all the static files in subdirectories in /static/ (css, img, js, etc.) and to set a workable settings on both local and live production without switching something in settings.py for deployment ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Normally you'd just put them under static as you want so they're accessible by manage.py and the devserver, and then run collectstatic to copy them to somewhere for serving by the frontend...

Comment: I made a "collectstatic" and all my files are in the /static/ directory but in local there are not accessible :/

Comment: If i'm not wrong, django doesn't let your `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` name be the same. meaning you can't have your static files in a folder called "static" and set url to "static" too. so i think if you change the url or static folder it should work. in production nginx handle this and it won't get to django so i think that's why it works there. try it out and let me know.

Comment: No sorry it doesn't work. I put STATIC_URL = '/s/'.
If I make a collectstatic, Django returns me : 0 static files copied to '/Volumes/Data/Projets/sitepro/sitepro/static', 1197 unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution :

After moving my static directory from the root directory of Django the folder of my main app, I made a collectstatic with that settings :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error also happens when you forgot to add quotes XD

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static note/main.css %}"> # wrong
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'note/main.css' %}"> # right
```